# $\mathbb Z_{15}$ inside the non-abelian group of order 75.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product

I know that any abelian group of order $75$ has a $\mathbb Z_{15}$ inside it.I was just wondering if there is a $\mathbb Z_{15}$ inside the non-abelian group of order $75$.

If there is a normal subgroup of order $5$ inside it then I can take direct product with a $\mathbb Z_3$ to get a $\mathbb Z_{15}.$

Also,$Aut(\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_5)\cong GL_2(\mathbb F_5)$.I was trying to look if there is an order $3$ element inside $GL_2(\mathbb F_5)$,which has an eigenvector inside $ \mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_5$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. If there is really a $\mathbb Z_{15}$ inside it, please  give me hints.I want to finish it myself.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531504/construct-a-non-abelian-group-of-order-75?rq=1 at the end of the answer there is a representation of the (only) non-abelian group of order $75$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ad-hoc answer, that does not require the knowledge of the structure of the (unique, up to isomorphism) non-abelian group of order $75$.

Let $G$ have order $75$. By Sylow's theorems, a Sylow $5$-subgroup $F$ is normal in $G$.

If $F$ is cyclic, since $3$ does not divide $\phi(25) = 20$, we have that $G$ is abelian.

So let $F$ be elementary abelian, so that it has $5 + 1 = 6$ subgroups of order $5$. Suppose $G$ has a subgroup $C$ of order $15$, which is thus cyclic. Then a Sylow $3$-subgroup $T$ acts by conjugacy on the $5$ subgroups of order $5$ of $F$ other than the one in $C$, so that it normalises at least one other, and thus centralises it.

We have obtained that $G$ is abelian if it has a subgroup of order $15$.

Comment: Nice answer, +1! Question : The only non-abelian group of order $75$ has a group representation given by $\langle x,y,t : x^5=y^5 =t^3 = e , xy=yx,txt^{-1} = y, tyt^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}\rangle$. Can we prove from here that there's no element of order $15$ and finish the problem? It looks like any candidate element will contain some $t$s, but I can't work out the exact details.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, thanks. As I see it$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$, $V =\Span{x, y}$ is elementary abelian of order $5^{2}$, i.e. a vector space of dimension $2$ over the field $F$ with $5$ element. Any element outside $V$ will induce on $V$ a linear transformation with matrix $\tau = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ or its inverse. Now $\tau$ has no eigenvalue $1$. This means none of the elements outside $V$ (which are the elements of order $3$ of the group) centralises an element of order $5$.

Comment: Thank you very much, the reply was nice.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, you're welcome.